# In mysql how to get users that have no event X in past 14 days and neither in the future

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider I have the following table and current date is `2022-09-01`:

[image]

**Requirement**: I want to get all users that have no `event_name` like `cbt care` in the **past 14 days and onwards into the future**.

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM test_table
WHERE event_name LIKE "%cbt care%"
  AND start_date <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
;
```

Which returns:

[image]

The issue is that `user_id = x` does have a `cbt care` event in `2022-09-10` which is 9 days ahead of current date (`2022-09-01`).

How to return only users satisfy requirement posted above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT user_id,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN event_name LIKE '%cbt care%' AND start_date 
    > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 14 day THEN 1 END) AS count_recent
FROM test_table
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING count_recent = 0;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/64j7L1VZsVdLYqmcQ2NrvV/0

The `CASE` expression returns 1 for each row with the conditions you described (a specific event name and a start date after the date 14 days ago, which includes all of the future dates too). For rows that don't match that condition, the `CASE` returns NULL. There's an implicit `ELSE NULL` in any `CASE` expression.

`COUNT(<expr>)`, like many set functions, ignores NULLs. It will only count the occurrences of non-NULL values. So if the count returns 0, then the `CASE` returned only NULLs, which means there are no recent or future 'cbt care' events for that user.

Comment: Amazing, that worked can you explain a bit more this part particularly not sure how that translate to no start date in 14 days in past until the future: `start_date 
    > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 14 day THEN 1 END`

Comment:  thanks so much @Bill Karwin really appreciate the explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
select id   
      ,user_id  
      ,event_name   
      ,start_date
from  (
       select * 
             ,count(case when abs(datediff(curdate(),start_date)) <= 14 and event_name like "%cbt care%" then 1 end) over (partition by user_id) as cw
       from   t
       ) t
where  cw = 0
```

| id | user_id | event_name | start_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | cbt care | 2022-06-01 20:00:00 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=189badde347fb459f8db74e130dbeb91&hide=1)